# How do i display data from multiple lists and sources in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to have a web part which displays a list of items. This would not be a sharepoint list but a list from multiple datasources e.g. output has a total of 8 columns

2 columns are from a sharepoint list (Users) ,
2 columns are from a custom sharepoint list ,
3 columns are accessed from a web service to a external system (e.g. share price from yahoo) ,1 columns is calculated (complex calculation) using the other 5 columns

How would i do this? What controls/objects would i need?

I am most interested in what control/object would best output the data. Assume i have a custom object with the 8 properties in visual studio code. I don't think i can do this with an SPView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the plain ASP.NET table control. It is simple to use and powerful enough if all you need is to show the data as a table. Logically, it corresponds to the *table* element of HTML. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.90).aspx

*SPView* class represents a list view in the SharePoint object model. As far as I know, it does not perform any content rendering.